# Problem with Regex

Tags: regex, perl, text-files, matching

I have a perl file that takes in txt files and compares them to other words in another txt file if they match then the file gets moved to another folder

I'm currently getting this error:

```
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\b( <-- HERE who\b/ at filter.pl line 45.
```

My perl file line 45 is:

```
if ($x =~ m/\b$word\b/) {
```

I don't know if it has anything to do with the rest of the file but I'll put my code up just incase!!

```
$dirtoget="/Users/jennie/crimes/";
opendir(IMD, $dirtoget) || die("Cannot open directory");
@thefiles= readdir(IMD);

foreach $f (@thefiles){
    if ($f =~ m/.txt/){
    #print "matches a txt file\n";
#print $f;
        open (FILE, "/Users/jennie/crimes/$f")or die"Cannot open FILE";

        if ( FILE eq "" ) {

            close FILE;
        }
        else{
       # print "In the Else\n";
            while (<FILE>) {
                foreach $word(split) {
                    foreach $x (@triggers) {
                        if ($x =~ m/\b$word\b/) {

                            print $word,"\n";
                                print $f,"\n";

                            copy("/Users/jennie/crimes/$f","/Users/jennie/crimeStories/$f")or die "Copy failed: $!";
                    close FILE;
                    } 
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
closedir(IMD);
exit 0;
```

The error doesn't make much sense to me I'm far from a whiz at regular expressions:-(

Comment: I do not believe that `\b` is appropriate here. Remember that `\b` **really** means `(?:(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(?=\w))` — just as `\B` really means `(?:(?<=\w)(?=\w)|(?<!\w)(?!\w))`. Contrary to popular and widespread misunderstanding, `\b` **does not mean** something like either `(?<=^)|(?<=\s))` when it falls to the left of something or else like `(?=$|\s`) when it falls to the right of something. This confusion is the source of innumerable progam errors both in Perl code and in anything else that uses `\b` in its regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're interpolating the contents of `$word` directly into the regex. This means any metacharacters in `$word` will be interpreted as metacharacters, potentially breaking your regex.

If you want to match the literal contents of `$word`, use `\Q` and `\E`:

```
$x =~ m/\b\Q$word\E\b/
```

---

Additionally, as @goreSplatter mentioned in the comments, you've got another broken regex further up the page:

```
$f =~ /.txt/
```

First of all, `.` is a metacharacter that matches *any character*. Second of all, it's not anchored - the regex will succeed if that character sequence appears anywhere in the filename. So for example, it *will* match `"thisisnotatxtfile.bin"`.

You can use the [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.2/lib/File/Basename.pm) module to extract *just* the file extension and test it, or you can modify the regex by escaping the `.` and anchoring it to the end of the filename:

```
$f =~ /\.txt$/
```

Comment: Wouldn't that *literally* match `$word` rather than what's *in* `$word`?

Comment: @goreSplatter: No, variable interpolation still happens even inside `\Q-\E`. Take a look at perlop - it explicitly calls out that you can't include a literal `$` inside `\Q-\E`, because it will be interpolated.

Comment: Good answer, then. Could you hint at `$f =~ m/.txt/` in your answer, too?

Comment: Unless you can guarantee that `$word` contains nothing but alphanumunder characters alone, using `\b` around it is almost certainly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because `$word` contains a metacharacter. A `(` in this case, which denotes the start of a capturing group. What this means is that your regex will be broken as `$word` can contain metacharacters. You can use `\Q` and `\E` to make sure that the contents of `$word` are "quoted" so that they will not be interpreted as metacharacters:

<s>$x =~ m/\b\Q$word\E\b/</s>

There is more information [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

**EDIT**

Based on tchrist's comment, the `\b` wouldn't make sense in this context unless you can ensure that `$word` contains only alphanumeric characters. But in general, to get around your problem, use:

```
$x = m/\Q$word\E/
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between what happens to that when `$word` contains say "fred" and when it contains "(fred)"?  I submit that this entire approach is flawed *ab initio.*

Comment: @tchrist Excellent point. The `\b` s don't make sense unless you can ensure that `$word` contains only alphanumeric characters. Hadn't even thought of that. You're right, it would be even more broken.

Comment: Thanks, that’s much better.  See my longish comment on the OP’s question above for what may — or may not be — a pair of whitespace‐sensitive boundaries that might be more in line with the sort of thing folks are expecting out of `\b`. The problem with those is you have to write them as specifically either left or else right edge. You can’t just have one definition of an edge that works for both sides the way the `\b` and `\B` definitions I give there work. Well, for sometimes rather dubious values of ‘work’, that is. :)

Comment: @tchrist My experience and knowledge with Perl remains at the amateur level since I am self-taught (with perl) and don't really do perl professionally. Such subtleties often get past me. It's great to learn about them, so thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Hey, I’m as much the Perl autodidact as you are! :)